# Finding right potentiometer to control the speed of a 240v DC, .5amp, permanent magnet motor

Tags: potentiometer

I have a faceting machine with a 240v, .5amp, 3000 rpm, permanent magnet motor which is repeatedly burning out the JH-50KA potentiometer which controls it speed.

I am not sure this is the correct (original) pot as I purchased the machine secondhand, can anyone suggest how I might resolve this, I have very limited electronics knowledge and live in a rural area with few people with electronics knowledge about.

Comment: To get help repairing things on this site, you need to have some knowledge about electrical and electronic theory and repair. Also you need the proper test equipment. My advice would be to seek assistance from one of the few people in your area with some experience. You should be ready to present all identification and rating information marked on the motor and control equipment. You will also need whatever you have as instructional material and documentation. If you can't have someone visit you, you will need photos and scanned images.

Comment: Thanks Charles, looks like i try the local tv repair man.

Comment: You might ask on groups specifically related to faceting machines (lapidary groups?) Motors aren't normally controlled by potentiometers so the question doesn't make much sense. Unless the pot is part of a motor speed control PCB. Now those are readily available for many types of motor.